# detect two files in a folder in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I need a code that detects if there is two files with the same extension and i need it to execute a different code.

1. Detect if the folder is two *.txt files i need it to
2. Echo there is two text files in this folder please remove one and continue

But if there is only one text file keep the code running

Im currently using this code to detect whether there isn't any files in the folder

```
If not exist Files\*.txt echo there is no lyrics
```

Maybe if we could combine this as well something like

```
  if text file equal to 0 echo no lyrics

  if text file equal to 1 echo.

  if text file Gtr 1 ech there is more than on text file in the folder
```

The code will be used twice one for text file and the other for .ogg audio files

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DIR /B` lists files, one per line, without header or footer info

`FIND /C` counts the number of matching lines, `/V ""` matches any line

`FOR /F` processes the results of a command

```
for /f %%N in ('dir /b "Files\*.txt" ^| find /c /v ""') do (
  if %%N equ 0 echo No lyrics
  if %%N equ 1 echo(
  if %%N gtr 1 echo There is more than one text file in the folder
)
```